# How to use corporate Ivy instance for grails dependency management to resolve internal artifacts

Tags: grails, ivy, dependency-management

All,

I have a straightforward out-of-the-box Grails project without any customizations. I have a simple page, simple controller, simple service; no problem.

Problem:
I would like to interact with our own software platform via its API. For that I need to refer to our internal jar artifacts. We have our own Ivy repository where we manage internal/external dependencies. I was unable to configure BuildConfig.groovy to point to the internal repository. Here is what I tried based on [these instructions](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html)

```
/*
 * Configure our resolver.
 */
def libResolver = new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()
['libraries', 'builds'].each {
    libResolver.addArtifactPattern(
            "http://my.repository/${it}/" +
            "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact].[ext]")

    libResolver.addIvyPattern(
            "http://my.repository/${it}/" +
            "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact].[ext]")
}

libResolver.name = "my-repository"
libResolver.settings = ivySettings

resolver libResolver
```

This fails pointing to the offending line

```
resolver libResolver
```

Researching I found just a few articles about this, removed the offending line, got more errors. Removed more offending lines, no errors, but specifying my dependencies in the "dependencies" section did not resolve them at all.

Question:

Has anyone successfully managed to configure a grails project with their internal ivy repo for dependency management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is.

```
  grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
     ...

        repositories {
            inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins
            resolver XXXLibResolver(dependencyManager)
            grailsPlugins()
            ...
        }

    ....

    def DependencyResolver XXXLibResolver(IvyDependencyManager dependencyManager) {
        DefaultRepositoryCacheManager nocache = new DefaultRepositoryCacheManager();
        nocache.setUseOrigin(true);
        nocache.name = "nocache";

        dependencyManager.ivySettings.addRepositoryCacheManager(nocache);

        def XXXHome = System.getenv("XXX_HOME")
        if (XXXHome) {
            XXXHome = new File(XXXHome).absolutePath
            def fileSystemResolver = new FileSystemResolver()
            fileSystemResolver.cache = nocache.name
            fileSystemResolver.local = true
            fileSystemResolver.name = 'XXX-lib-repo'
            fileSystemResolver.addIvyPattern("${XXXHome}/libraries/[organisation]/[module]/ivys/ivy-[revision].xml")
            fileSystemResolver.addArtifactPattern("${XXXHome}/libraries/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]")
            fileSystemResolver.settings = dependencyManager.ivySettings
            return fileSystemResolver
        }
}
```

Comment: Aram, thank you for your answer. Where do I place this code section <code>def DependencyResolver XXXLibResolver(IvyDependencyManager dependencyManager) {....}</code> ?

Comment: This however does not answer the original question about ivy repository instance. This does resolve files in a local filesystem, but how does one point to a remote Ivy repo?

Comment: def DependencyResolver XXXLibResolver(IvyDependencyManager dependencyManager) {....}
is defined in grails.project.dependency.resolution scope 

=====
Yes I have copy of ivy repository in my local file system.
I belie you can easy switch from FileSystemResolver()
to org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver(), just read documentation.